# How to set text color for all the TextViews programatically?

Tags: android, textview

I am creating 8 `TextView`s dynamically and adding them in my layout. I want to set their text color. So I have declared the color code in my color.xml and I am setting it as:

```
txt1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.off_white));
```

But I have to redundantly do this for all the `TextView`s individually. Is there a way wherein I can set it globally for all the TextViews. Something similar to what we can do in jQuery for example:

```
$('input[type="text"]').css('color','white');
```

Comment: it depends how you created `TextView`.

Comment: Android doesn't support such global API to set the text color. A for loop will be a quick way and easy way to set colors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Custom `TextView` for that.

As shown here:

```
MyTextView mTxt = new MyTextView(getApplicationContext());  //Use MyTextView instead of TextView where you want to apply color
mTxt.setText("Some text");
```

Your custom class `MyTextView` would be something like:

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView{

    public MyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.setTextColor(Color.GREEN); //change color as per your need here. 
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your custom text view for that and then use instance of that textview everywhere.

Example -

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView{

    public MyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        setTextColor(R.color.holo_orange_light);
    }

}
```

Comment: For this specific question, you don't need to overload all of the functions. Just a nitpick, this works though.

Answer (score 1):

You may define `TextView` in XML file like following;

```
<TextView 
    android:text="My Text View"
    android:textColor="@color/myColor"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

And then inflate this layout, where you need to instantiate `TextView` in code like;

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
TextView tv1 = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, null);
```

Comment: check question heading it's programatically not in xml

Comment: @Rustam Yes. You just need to inflate instead of instantiating programatically.