# How to change text color in custom textview?

Tags: android, android-canvas

How to change text color in custom textview?
Total text and words separately?
paint.color does not affect

```
class Custom(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet) : TextView(context, attributeSet) {

      override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
             super.onDraw(canvas)

             paint.color = Color.BLUE

       }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500873/how-to-set-text-color-for-all-the-textviews-programatically

Comment: need to change color through canvas