# Set text color for multiple TextViews at once

Tags: java, android, textview

Is there a way to set A text color for multiple textviews programmatically with one line of code (in Java/Android)?

```
public void MakeAllTxtWhite(){
    TextView[] alltxt = {txt1, txt2, txt3, txt4, txt5,txt6,txt7,txt8, txt9, txt10, txt11, txt12, txt13, txt14, txt15, txt16,
         txt17, txt18, txt19, txt20, txt21, txt22, txt23, txt24, txt25, txt26, txt27, txt28, txt29, txt30, txt31, txt32, txt33, txt34};
    for(TextView i : alltxt){
        i.setTextColor(i.getContext().getColor(R.color.white));
    }
}
```

I know it is possible to put all the txvs in a list and iterate through it, but I wonder if there is another more suitable method.

Comment: Can you please add the code you tried to write ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Create your own class that extends ```TextView``` and set the text color there. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500873/how-to-set-text-color-for-all-the-textviews-programatically).

Comment: ok thanks @Enowneb im going to try that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say what you are doing is fine. There is no such API to update text color of multiple TextView's. But it doesn't mean you can't extract your own helper method somewhere and use it.

And if you wish you can avoid adding TextViews to array. For example, we can write

```
public class ViewHelpers {
    public static void setTextColor(@ColorInt int colorResourceId, TextView... views) {
        for (TextView textView : views) {
            textView.setTextColor(colorResourceId);
        }
    }
}
```

And later in code use it as follows:

```
ViewHelpers.setTextColor(R.color.myColor, textView1, textView2, textView3);
```